# What database technology do Bitcoin exchanges use?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox, database

I wonder if they use a relational database like MySQL or do they opt for a NoSQL like CouchDB or MongoDB.

The Bitcoinica source code reveals that they used a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple Bitcoin Exchanges out there, most likely they are using different DB Systems.
To be sure you should contact the particular representatives of the Exchanges.